# No image strip file and no single request with gwts ClientBundle ImageResource

Tags: gwt

the purpose of gwts clientbundle + imageresource is to reduce the number of http request to one and to minimize the amount of transfered bytes while clientbundle creates a single jpg strip file which contains all my jpg-pics.
As example i have ten pics, clientbundle would put all these ten pics into a single jpg-strip-file 
and if the app would call all these images there would be only one http request for the single-jpg-strip file.
thats what i understand.
The thing is that clientbundle is not creating a single strip file.
It creates ten cacheable files but when i am enabling caching it still does not create this single stripfile.
iam understanding something wrong what the purpose of clientbundle is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two small misunderstandings in your question:

- ClientBundle will only generate a sprited image for IE6/7; for all other browsers it'll use `data:` URLs (at least that's the default configuration) until some threshold on the size of the image and then will directly reference the image as an external one (not sprited).
- ClientBundle won't generate sprited images (for IE6/7) for images with lossy compression (such as JPEGs), only for those with lossless one (such as PNG or GIF), and only if they're not animated, and only if they're not too big (threshold is [controlled](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.5.1/user/src/com/google/gwt/resources/rg/ImageBundleBuilder.java) by a `gwt.imageResource.maxBundleSize` system property and defaults to 256 pixels)

In your case, I'd say that the JPEG images cross the threshold so they're not inlined as `data:` URLs, and because they are JPEG (i.e. with lossy compression) you don't see a sprited image generated either.

Note: there are several threshold actually for the `data:` URL:

- one on the size of the file: https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.5.1/user/src/com/google/gwt/resources/rebind/context/AbstractResourceContext.java
- one on the size of the `data:` URL (after base64-encoding): https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.5.1/user/src/com/google/gwt/resources/rebind/context/InlineResourceContext.java